How can I connect the Azure Go SDK to Azure Government?
Setting the AZURE_ENVIRONMENT variable has no effect when using the Go SDK. How would I connect to the Azure Government cloud?

Unlike with some methods of connecting an SDK to Azure, there is no environment variable you can set to control which cloud is connected to (e.g. AZURE_ENVIRONMENT). Instead, you have to pass the configuration in while instantiating the client in code.
First, create a credential like you would when connecting to the public Azure cloud instead of Azure Government.
cred, err := azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(nil)

Then, use the credential alongside an options structs where the desired cloud is selected. This works for both the approach where you instantiate a factory and then instantiate clients from it and the approach where you instaniate clients directly. Here's a factory example where a resource groups client is instantiated from the factory.
opts := azcore.ClientOptions{Cloud: cloud.AzureGovernment}
clientFactory, _ := armresources.NewClientFactory("<subscription ID>", cred, &arm.ClientOptions{
    ClientOptions: opts,
})
resourceGroupsClient = clientFactory.NewResourceGroupsClient()

Under the hood, a different host will be used by the SDK when it creates requests (e.g. "management.usgovcloudapi.net" instead of "management.azure.com" for Azure Government at time of writing).


One way to tell from the outside that the SDK is connecting to the right host is by testing it with a subscription ID that exists in the public cloud but not in Azure Government. It will return an error about the subscription not being found.
panic: GET https://management.usgovcloudapi.net/subscriptions/<subscription ID>/resourcegroups
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RESPONSE 404: 404 Not Found
ERROR CODE: SubscriptionNotFound
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
  "error": {
    "code": "SubscriptionNotFound",
    "message": "The subscription '<subscription ID>' could not be found."
  }
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

If it were connecting to a subscription that did exist, it would return an error about being unauthenticated or unauthorized or the API call would succeed.
Note that while parts of the documentation at time of writing do talk about the AZURE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable, it is in the previous-versions-quickstart.md part of the docs, which refers to the legacy way of using the Go SDK.
